# parse and extract info from string

Tags: python

i am using windows OS, python 2.7
I list all the available ports (COM1, 3, 4) and the current output is:

```
[('COM4', 'Neato Robotics USB Port (COM4)', 'USB VID:PID=2108:780C SNR=XXXX'), ('COM3', 'Intel(R) Active Management Technology - SOL (COM3)', 'PCI\\VEN_8086&DEV_9C3D&SUBSYS_05DE1028&REV_04\\3&11583659&0&B3'), ('COM1', 'Communications Port (COM1)', 'ACPI\\PNP0501\\0')]
```

My question is, I would like to use/connect to `COM4`. So I hope I can find a way to parse that port and use it afterwards. i.e. how to extract `COM4` from that long string? I plan to target it by PID.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Bit by bit:

```
>>> ports = [('COM4', 'Neato Robotics USB Port (COM4)', 'USB VID:PID=2108:780C SNR=XXXX'),
...          ('COM3', 'Intel(R) Active Management Technology - SOL (COM3)', 'PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_9C3D&SUBSYS_05DE1028&REV_04\3&11583659&0&B3'),
...          ('COM1', 'Communications Port (COM1)', 'ACPI\PNP0501\0')]

>>> ports[0]
('COM4', 'Neato Robotics USB Port (COM4)', 'USB VID:PID=2108:780C SNR=XXXX')

>>> ports[0][2]
'USB VID:PID=2108:780C SNR=XXXX'

>>> ports[0][2].split(':')
['USB VID', 'PID=2108', '780C SNR=XXXX']

>>> ports[0][2].split(':')[1]
'PID=2108'

>>> ports[0][2].split(':')[1].split('=')
['PID', '2108']

>>> ports[0][2].split(':')[1].split('=')[1]
'2108'

>>> int(ports[0][2].split(':')[1].split('=')[1])
2108
```

Comment: It works, thanks, Peter. I modify it a little bit to get PID 780C. NICE JOB! =)

Comment: Hi Peter, is there a way I can extract the COM port (COM4) by PID? In another word, how about we scan all the PID first, and extract the com port which is associated with PID 2018? Then I can use that COM port in the next step.

Answer (score 1):

<s>Let's say your string is stored in the `value` variable:</s>

```
value = "[('COM4', 'Neato Robotics USB Port (COM4)', 'USB VID:PID=2108:780C SNR=XXXX'), ('COM3', 'Intel(R) Active Management Technology - SOL (COM3)', 'PCI\\VEN_8086&DEV_9C3D&SUBSYS_05DE1028&REV_04\\3&11583659&0&B3'), ('COM1', 'Communications Port (COM1)', 'ACPI\\PNP0501\\0')]"
data = [tuple(item[1:][:-1].split("', '")) for item in value[2:][:-2].split('), (')]
```

Given:

```
data = [('COM4', 'Neato Robotics USB Port (COM4)', 'USB VID:PID=2108:780C SNR=XXXX'), ('COM3', 'Intel(R) Active Management Technology - SOL (COM3)', 'PCI\\VEN_8086&DEV_9C3D&SUBSYS_05DE1028&REV_04\\3&11583659&0&B3'), ('COM1', 'Communications Port (COM1)', 'ACPI\\PNP0501\\0')]
```

Then a regex can be used to extract the PID value:

```
import re
pid = re.search('VID:PID=.*:(.*) ', data[0][2]).group(1)
```

If you want both VID and PID:

```
import re
match = re.search('VID:PID=(.*):(.*) ', data[0][2])
if match and len(match.groups()) > 0:
    vid = match  and match.group(1) or None
    pid = match and match.group(2) or None
```

## Update

To map a port to PID, or vice versa:

```
import re

data = [('COM4', 'Neato Robotics USB Port (COM4)', 'USB VID:PID=2108:780C SNR=XXXX'), ('COM3', 'Intel(R) Active Management Technology - SOL (COM3)', 'PCI\\VEN_8086&DEV_9C3D&SUBSYS_05DE1028&REV_04\\3&11583659&0&B3'), ('COM1', 'Communications Port (COM1)', 'ACPI\\PNP0501\\0')]

def extract_pid(dev_string):
    match = re.search('PID=.*:(.*) ', dev_string)
    groups = match and match.groups()
    return groups and len(groups) > 0 and groups[0] or None

port_to_pid_dict = dict((item[0], extract_pid(item[2])) for item in data)
# port_to_pid_dict = {'COM1': None, 'COM3': None, 'COM4': '2108'}
pid_to_port_dict = dict((extract_pid(item[2]), item[0]) for item in data if 'PID=' in item[2])
# pid_to_port_dict = {'2108': 'COM4'}
```

And then you can use `pid_to_port_dict['2018']`, which gives `'COM4'`.

Of course, additional logic would be necessary if you had multiple instances of the same product connected to the computer at the same time:

```
import collections

pid_to_port_dict = collections.defaultdict(list)
for item in data:
    pid = extract_pid(item[2])
    if pid:
        pid_to_port_dict[pid].append(item[0])
```

Now `pid_to_port_dict['2018']` will result with an array of ports the products with specific productId are connected to: `['COM4']`.

It would probably be a better idea to check for both product ID and vendor ID as multiple products from various vendors can have the same product ID.

## Update 2

Here is how I would do it. Click [here](https://repl.it/B2IH/1) for an interactive example.

```
import collections
import re

class Device:
    def __init__(self, vendorId, productId, port):
        self.vendorId = vendorId
        self.productId = productId
        self.port = port

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.__str__()

    def __str__(self):
        return "Device {}:{} at {}".format(self.vendorId, self.productId, self.port)

def create_defaultdict_with_list():
    return collections.defaultdict(list)

class DeviceParser:
    def __init__(self, devices):
        self.devices = devices

    @staticmethod
    def _parse(device_string, port):
        match = re.search('VID:PID=(.*):(.*) ', device_string)
        if match and len(match.groups()) == 2:
            return Device(vendorId=match.group(1),
                          productId=match.group(2),
                          port=port)
        return None

    def parse_as_list(self):
        devices = []
        for port, description, dev_str in self.devices:
            dev = self._parse(dev_str, port)
            if dev:
                devices.append(dev)
        return devices

    def parse_as_vendor_map(self):
        vendors = collections.defaultdict(create_defaultdict_with_list)
        for port, description, dev_str in self.devices:
            dev = self._parse(dev_str, port)
            if not dev:
                continue
            vendors[dev.vendorId][dev.productId].append(dev)
        return vendors

def main():
    data = [
        ('COM4', 'Neato Robotics USB Port (COM4)', 'USB VID:PID=2108:780C SNR=XXXX'),
        ('COM3', 'Intel(R) Active Management Technology - SOL (COM3)', 'PCI\\VEN_8086&DEV_9C3D&SUBSYS_05DE1028&REV_04\\3&11583659&0&B3'),
        ('COM1', 'Communications Port (COM1)', 'ACPI\\PNP0501\\0')
    ]
    parser = DeviceParser(data)
    devices = parser.parse_as_list()
    print('recognized device list:', devices)
    vendors = parser.parse_as_vendor_map()
    print('device by vendorId and productId:', vendors['2108']['780C'])
    print('port of device:', vendors['2108']['780C'][0].port)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```